# Delay in passing data using segue Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, segue

I'm trying to pass the storeId to another viewController using segue, however, there seems to be a delay when passing data? Data is "nil" at first, I have to tap it again in order it to pass the correct data.

Here is my code

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   
    self.passStoreData = self.storeList [indexPath.row];
    self.passStoreId = [self.storeList [indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"storeId"];
    self.passStoreName = [self.storeList [indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"storeName"];
    NSString *store = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ : %@", self.passStoreId, self.passStoreName];
    
    [self.storeButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", store] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    storeTable.hidden = YES;
    
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showOrder" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    OrderListViewController *orderListVc = [segue destinationViewController];

    orderListVc.theStoreId = self.passStoreData;
    
}
```

What can I do to avoid the delay in passing the data using segue? Thank you.

Comment: How/where are you handling `theStoreId` in the `OrderListViewController`?

Comment: Yes, theStoreId is in the h file of OrderListViewController

Comment: Yes but where in the lifecycle of the `OrderListViewController` do you use it to know it only appears after the 2nd open?

Comment: Ah yes, `self.setStoreId.text = [self.theStoreId valueForKey:@"storeId"];` I used it in order to set the label as the store ID.

Did this answer your question? I'm sorry, I'm just starting out.

Comment: Almost. Within what function in `OrderListViewController` are you setting that?

Comment: Show the code at the destination view controller.

Comment: It is under viewDidLoad

Comment: Just as I thought. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

By the time you call `[segue destinationViewController]`, the `OrderListViewController` is loaded and ready to use. So any code in `viewDidLoad` will already have been called, way before you set `theStoreId`.

Move your view setup code to `viewWillAppear:` and it should work.

Comment: I moved the code to viewWillAppear: `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    self.setStoreId.text = [self.theStoreId valueForKey:@"storeId"];
}`

And it still has delay in passing the storeId.

Comment: Try `viewDidAppear:`, make sure you call `super.viewDidAppear` too. Maybe post the code in your question.

Comment: I tried to use viewDidAppear as well, the delay is still there and it wasn't able to populate the tableView. With viewWillAppear, the passing of storeId still has delay but after another tap, it was able to be passed and able to populate the tableView.

I have edited my original question to add the viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear of `OrderListViewController`

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After trying and researching. I found the answer to this.

I used `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()` to run it on main thread and the passing of data through segue was not delayed. Thank you